Vue router doesn't stay in the same page after page refresh
Here's the translation:
I am working on a project using Vue^3.4.21, vue-route: ^4.3.0, and VITE ^5.2.8, and I have the following problem: if I am on the page /someanotherpath and press F5 to refresh the page, instead of staying on the same page, I am redirected to '/'.
What I tried to do:
1. Remove `router.beforeEach`. Even after removing it, it still redirects to / instead of staying on the same page after refreshing.
2. Add the `:key` prop to the `router-view`:
<router-view :key="route.fullPath"></router-view>
router file
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";
import Home from "@/views/login/Login.vue";
import PasswordRecovery from "@/views/login/PasswordRecovery.vue";

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        component: Home,
        name: "home",
        meta: { displayName: "home", icon: "home", authRequired: true },
    },
    {
        path: "/someanotherpath",
        component: PasswordRecovery,
        name: "someanotherpath",
        meta: { displayName: "", authRequired: false },
    },
];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.authRequired)) {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

        if (token) {
            try {
                const decoded = jwtDecode(token);

                if (decoded.exp && decoded?.exp > Date.now() / 1000) {
                    next();
                } else {
                    localStorage.clear();
                    if (
                        to.path !== "/login" &&
                        to.name !== "password-recovery"
                    ) {
                        next("/login");
                    } else {
                        next();
                    }
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);

                localStorage.clear();
                if (to.path !== "/login" && to.name !== "password-recovery") {
                    next("/login");
                } else {
                    next();
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (to.path !== "/login" && to.name !== "password-recovery") {
                next("/login");
            } else {
                next();
            }
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

export default router;

Vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "url";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    resolve: {
        alias: [
            {
                find: "@",
                replacement: fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
            },
            {
                find: "@assets",
                replacement: fileURLToPath(
                    new URL("./src/shared/assets", import.meta.url)
                ),
            },
            {
                find: "@cmp",
                replacement: fileURLToPath(
                    new URL("./src/shared/cmp", import.meta.url)
                ),
            },
            {
                find: "@stores",
                replacement: fileURLToPath(
                    new URL("./src/shared/stores", import.meta.url)
                ),
            },
            {
                find: "@use",
                replacement: fileURLToPath(
                    new URL("./src/shared/use", import.meta.url)
                ),
            },
        ],
    },
    build: {
        sourcemap: true,
    },
});


How do you run the project? Changes in routing on page refresh are commonly caused by server config that isn't compatible with client-side routing

I just run "npm run dev". I'm not sure if this is what you asked

What is "dev" script? It's "vite dev" by default but it's unknown what's it in your case. What I described could be a problem if you used "build" and deployed it to a server. Otherwise I don't see what the problem is, especially if it persists when you remove beforeEach. Please, provide a way to reproduce, it needs to be debugged what's going on
